Issue with .NET MAUI App Handling Shared Files When in Background
I’m developing a .NET MAUI application and I’ve encountered an issue related to file sharing. My app is designed to handle shared files from other apps or sources. However, I’m facing a System.InvalidOperationException: 'Window was already created' error under specific circumstances.
Here’s the behavior I’ve observed:
When the app is in the background and I attempt to share a file to it, everything works fine.
But if the app is already open and running in the foreground, trying to share a file causes the aforementioned exception.
It seems like the app is trying to create a new window over the existing one, which is not allowed. This issue only occurs when the app is active; if I close the app from the background and then share the file, it resumes and processes the share intent correctly.
I’m looking for a way to check if the app is already open and, if so, to properly handle the incoming share intent without causing an exception. Ideally, the app should be able to manage the shared file whether it’s in the foreground or background.
Has anyone else faced a similar issue with .NET MAUI apps? Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
What I tried: I have an application that handles file sharing from other apps or sources. When the app is in the background and I share a file to it, it works fine. However, if the app is already open, sharing a file causes a System.InvalidOperationException: 'Window was already created' error.
What I was expecting: I was expecting the app to handle the shared file seamlessly, whether it was in the foreground or background, without throwing any exceptions.

Did the problem appear on android platform?

Yes, the problem is in Android

Can overriding the OnNewIntent method make the intent has correct ClipData?

You can try to set the MainActivity's launch mode as SingleTask,SingleTop. Such as:
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme",LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,

The default mode is Standard:

The system creates a new instance of the activity in the task it was started from and routes the intent to it. The activity can be instantiated multiple times, each instance can belong to different tasks, and one task can have multiple instances.

if you use the SingleTask mode, you can override the MainActivity's OnNewIntent method:
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent? intent)
 {
     base.OnNewIntent(intent);
     Intent = intent;
 }


When I add this code, the Intent.ClipData is sent empty.

You can refer to the code about overriding onnewintent methoed in the answer. @HassanVahedi

@LiyunZhang-MSFT setting the LaunchMode seems to fix this issue for me, thanks!
